# PHP not always getting value from $_GET

Tags: php, cross-browser, querystringparameter

I have a Wordpress shortcode that will display the appropriate image based on some values passed through the query string. It gets the value with `$_GET['utm_content']`.

Not sure why it would be a browser thing, but... it works as expected 100% of the time in non-incognito Chrome. With Chrome in incognito mode, Firefox and Safari, it only gets the value a percentage of the time. When it doesn't get it `isset($_GET['utm_content'])` fails....

Here's the entire function. You can see my debugging code at the end.

```
add_shortcode('bene_show_img', 'bene_show_img');
function bene_show_img( $atts, $content = null ) {
        $utm_campaign = isset($_GET['utm_campaign']) ? $_GET['utm_campaign'] : 'not set';
        $utm_content = isset($_GET['utm_content']) ? $_GET['utm_content'] : 'not set';

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'base_path' => 'wp-content/uploads',
                'img_path' => substr( substr_replace( substr($utm_campaign, 0, 8) , '/', 4, 0 ), 0, 7 ),
                'img_base_name' => substr($utm_campaign, 8),
                'img_ver' => $utm_content,
                'img_ext' => 'png'
        ), $atts ) ); 

        $bp = esc_attr($base_path);
        $p = esc_attr($img_path);
        $bn = esc_attr($img_base_name);
        $v = esc_attr($img_ver);
        $e = esc_attr($img_ext) . '?r=' . rand();

        // TODO: if the final path does not point to an image, try decreasing then increasing the 
        // month by 1... 


        

        // Return a string to display on the page
        $tag = <<<EOD
                <img width="1024" height="535" src="/$bp/$p/$bn-$v-1024x538.$e" 
                class="attachment-large size-large" alt="" 
                srcset="/$bp/$p/$bn-$v-1024x538.$e 1024w, 
                /$bp/$p/$bn-$v-300x175.$e 300w, 
                /$bp/$p/$bn-$v-768x401.$e 768w, 
                /$bp/$p/$bn-$v.$e 1200w" 
                sizes="(max-width: 1024px) 100vw, 1024px"> 
        EOD;

        return "<h2>XX $utm_content $utm_campaign XX</h2>" . $tag;
        //return $tag;
}
```

What am I missing?

In case my error not overly visible, you can see the behavior live at: http://wordpress-310389-952347.cloudwaysapps.com/20200709-1/?utm_campaign=20200709page&utm_content=1a

### **UPDATE**

Just to be sure it wasn't any sort of weird shortcode thing, I added the following to functions.php and get consistent results when viewing the URL above

```
add_shortcode('getit', 'getit');
function getit() {
    return $_GET['utm_content'];
}

echo '<pre>' . do_shortcode('[getit]') . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . getit() . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you var_dump (or debug) the $_GET in your wp-config.php to see if it exists at the beginning of the page load. Trying to see get this before anything in WordPress runs to rule out any code on the server being the issue. Many browsers (either natively or via extensions) will strip utm params, but I don't think that is the care here since it's inconsistent. So it's possible it's some WP code (maybe a plugin?) catching it.

Comment: @PhilF - adding `var_dimp($_GET)` to the top of wp-config yields `array(2) { ["utm_campaign"]=> string(12) "20200709page" ["utm_content"]=> string(2) "1a" }`

Comment: Every single time, correct? (Since you said your issue is inconsistent). What about any other plugins (like SEO/marketing/tracking/etc plugins) installed?

Comment: Ah, I see not by testing your link. So... this most likely means it has nothing to do with WordPress, since it's failing right at the beginning of php execution. So... It's either the browser stripping those arguments or the web server not passing them. Just to be doubly sure, you can move that code from your `wp-config.php` to the `index.php` in the document root before `require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';` line. If the result is the same, then you know you need to look outside your code.

Comment: ooops, my bad. No not every time. Only the times when the values were read correctly. When they're not, it displays `array(0) { } `. There was a 301 redirect plugin installed by our SEO person - I deactivated and don't see any difference.

Comment: Yea, that makes sense, this is failing way before your code or any plugin gets executed. What web server are you running and is there anything unusual in it's config?

Comment: Yup same thing when I moved the `var_dump` to `/index.php`. I don't even now where to begin to troubleshoot this. I'm on managed Wordpress hosting. Is this a tech support thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217771/discussion-between-phil-f-and-daveh0).